# Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular 4 project, project works fine but i get some errors like "Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined" in console window 40 times.

My html codes are like below;

```
<div [innerHtml]="helpObject.Description"></div>
```

And here is my component codes;

```
export class FooterComponent {
   helpObject: any;

   errorMsg: string;

   constructor(private _emService: EmService) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this._emService.getContent("help")
        .subscribe(resData => this.helpObject = resData,
            resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
   }
}
```

Comment: what does your helpObject consists of can you please specify the properties

Comment: Try this: `[innerHtml]="helpObject?.Description"`

Comment: it returns a class object in Json has property named Description

Comment: Thank you R. Richards. Why do i need to put question mark? Can u explain it? What are the differences of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably making a rookie mistake here, but this could be solved by making use of the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) on your `helpObject` to protect it from null or undefined values while you are waiting for the data (which is undefined at that very moment) to be rendered:

```
<div [innerHtml]="helpObject?.Description"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can use an `*ngIf` to solve your issue. This prevents that div from being rendered until `helpObject` is defined.

```
<div *ngIf="helpObject">
..
<div [innerHtml]="helpObject?.Description"></div>
..
</div>
```